# Ubuntu MATE: How replace <Alt+F1> by Super_L for opening the menu?

Tags: settings, mate

I'd like to open the MATE Menu with the Super_L key. Is it possible?

I tried this without result:

```
costales@netbook:~$ gconftool-2 --get /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/panel_main_menu
<Alt>F1
costales@netbook:~$ gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/panel_main_menu --type string "Super_L"
costales@netbook:~$ gconftool-2 --get /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/panel_main_menu
Super_L
costales@netbook:~$
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

- Open the dconf Editor in System Tools menu. Go to
- /org/mate/marco/global-keybindings/panel-main-menu
- Set Super_L as value
- Logout & Login again. It's done.

Comment: This worked for me in Mate 16.04, wheras the gconftool solution didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you missed the `<` and `>` symbols. Try this:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/panel_main_menu --type string "<Super_L>"
```